# Best way to model a single user with multiple usernames

Tags: database-design

I'm looking to write a website where a user will login with their email address and password, but can have multiple usernames.

The context is a social gaming website. This may result in a user wishing to have more than one username. For example, one username for playing within a team (prefixed or similar) and one for playing alone.

I've been trying to rack my brains over the best way to represent this in my database, so far I've come up with:

[image: Attempt One]

In this design, only one row in username per user will have active set to true. This smells a bit to me. What if no rows for a given user have active set to true?

[image: Attempt Two]

I guess with this one, we're more or less guaranteed to have a username for each user, and the owned usernames table provides a list of usernames owned by the user. It feels better, but then there's duplicate information (the username is specified in two tables when active).

Anyone have better ideas of how I can structure this? Is there a common pattern for this?

Essentially, what I am envisaging is some way of providing functionality to my website of having one user per person, logging in with an email and password, and linking one or more usernames to that user.

I guess a 1:N relationship between user and username where N > 0. I'm just not sure about how to model this effectively. Or indeed, if this is a sign that my desired functionality needs re-thinking.

There will be no formal notion of a team, this was just an example where a person would maybe want more than one username.

Of course, we could simplify this and force people who want separate usernames to sign up multiple times. This would simplify the database a huge amount, but it'd be more convenient to the user to allow one login for multiple usernames.

I'm thinking of limiting this to start with to a maximum of 2 or 3, but I guess this doesn't change the design, just a front end limitation.

Answer (score 6):

You have clarified that you will not implement the team aspect in your system, but I consider that keeping the suggested approach for such scenario in this answer is still pertinent since it can be a useful example for other seekers.

Along with that, I have included some other contexts in which you could offer the option of having multiple *Usernames* (or *Nicknames*, or *Handles*), and a possibility that takes into account the common ASP.NET arrangement for dealing with *Users* and *Roles* data. These elements may serve to establish some analogies with the informational requirements of your own business environment.

## 1. User Profiles and Team Player Nicknames

#### 1.1 Business rules

According to my understanding of your description about the social gaming website, I consider that the following conceptual-level formulations are specially relevant:

- A *User* may be a *Player* of zero-one-or-many *Teams*
- A *Team* is made up of one-to-many *Players*, each of which must be a *User*

#### 1.2 IDEF1X diagrams

Then, I derived from those business rules the two IDEF1X<sup>**1**</sup> diagrams that are presented in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJNCc.jpg).

[image: Figure 1 - User Profiles and Team Player Nicknames IDEF1X Diagrams]

**1.2.1 Option A**

As you can see in such a diagram, there is a many-to-many (M:N) association or relationship between the entity types `Users` and `Teams`, which takes effect in the *associative* entity type called `TeamPlayer`.

The `UserProfile.UserId` PRIMARY KEY (PK for brevity) property migrates<sup>**2**</sup> to `TeamPlayer` as `PlayerId`, a role name that I have assigned to `UserProfile.UserId` in order to make it more meaningful in the context of its corresponding entity type, and these properties must be connected via a FOREIGN KEY (FK) defined in `TeamPlayer`.

On the other hand, `TeamPlayer.TeamNumber` is associated to `Team.TeamNumber` by virtue of another FK reference.

With this arrangement, one given `UserProfile` can hold

- one `Username` when acting as an individual, and
- one `Nickname` when he or she is carrying out the *role* of a `Player` for each of the `Teams` in which the `UserProfile` in question has joined.

**1.2.2 Option B**

This diagram is quite similar to the one referred in Option A, but it has an important aspect that is different, since I have moved the `TeamPlayer.Nickname` property to a separate entity type, which is called `Nickname`. This configuration is useful in case the *Nickname* value of a *Team Player* is optional, i.e., *TeamPlayers* may choose to provide or not provide a *Nickname*.

#### 1.3 Team Player Nickname uniqueness

The Option A daigram has an ALTERNATE KEY<sup>**3**</sup> (AK) defined for `TeamPlayer`, which is composed of two properties: `TeamNumber` and `Nickname`. In turn, the Option B diagram exhibits an AK in the `Nickname` entity type that is made up of `TeamNumber` and `Nickname`, as well. In this manner, both methods would provide UNIQUEness for a *Nickname* value within the context of a determined *Team* instance.

If you want to prevent the same *Nickname* value from being repeated in several *Team* occurrences, then you should set up an AK comprised of only one single property, that is, `Nickname`. This approach is valid for option A and Option B.

Alternatively, if you want to have the `Nickname` property set as NULLable (i.e., optional), you could define a “filtered” (or “conditional”, or “partial”, depending on the platform of use) UNIQUE constraint in Option A for supplying *Nickname* uniqueness in relation to a `Team` but, as I see it, proceeding this way things would get *less elegant*, so to speak.

## 2. People, User Profiles and Usernames

I created some more IDEF1X diagrams (presented in [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zYc4.jpg)) depicting different scenarios in which a given *Person* can have multiple *Usernames*, aiming to broaden the scope of this post. They are shown in the following section.

#### 2.1 IDEF1X diagrams

[image: Figure 2 - People UserProfiles and Usernames IDEF1X diagrams]

**2.1.1 Option A**

This option is representing the following conceptual business rules:

- A *Person* may log in via zero-or-one *UserProfile*
- A *UserProfile* has one-to-many *Usernames*

Thus, it is comparable to your first diagram, but I have added a `Person` entity type that is *optionally* connected to `UserProfile` via the `UserId` FK definition.

Another important addition is the `Username` PK, which is comprised of

- a FK reference to `UserProfile.UserId` and
- the `CreatedDateTime` property that represents the instant in which a given *Username* was inserted.

This allows you to get rid of the `Username.UsernameId` (or `username.id`, if you prefer) property.

In this regard, this excerpt from your question is very important:

> So, in this design, only one row in username per user will have active set to true. This smells a bit to me. What if no rows for a given user have active set to true?

Yes, you should establish a policy that states how many `Username` instances can have the `IsActive` property set to `'TRUE'` with respect to a precise `UserProfile`, whether exclusively one *Username* that is “active” at a given point in time, perhaps two, three, etc., or none at all. As you know, each possibility demands distinct validation methods.

But, if a certain *User* can have multiple *Usernames*, I do not think that there can be a problem if such a *User* does not have any “active” *Usernames*, since the log in credentials are the *Email* and *Password*. In this case, when no *Username* is “active”, you could display some sort of a “default message” indicating that situation.

**2.1.2 Option B**

This method is very alike to Option A, but it is less flexible, since I have integrated the `UserProfile` credentials into the `Person` entity type. By proceeding this way, you would force every *Person* to have a `LoginEmail` and a `Password`.

Conversely, Option A permits you to retain *Persons* (or *People*) that are not related to the *User* context in a clean and separate manner, without employing NULLable (i.e., optional) properties.

**2.1.3 Option C**

The diagram displayed as Option C describes the statements that follow:

- A *Person* may log in via zero-or-one *UserProfile*
- A *UserProfile* holds zero-one-or-many entries in *UsernameHistory*

This method implies notions pertaining to the subject known as *temporal databases*. You may find [my take on Scenario A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107575/63644) and [my response to Scenario B](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112314/63644) of relevance in this respect.

With this approach —once the schema depicted in this diagram is built on a certain SQL environment— you could retain the “active” *Username* in a, say, `UserProfile` table and all the “past versions” in a, say, `UsernameHistory` table.

As per the data manipulation factor, basically, every time that a `UserProfile` UPDATEs his or her `Username`, you save a *copy* of the last `Username` version in the `UsernameHistory` table. Each *History Version* is uniquely identified by a combination of the *Date and Time* datum in which such row was modified and, or course, the `UserId` FK that links the row in question with its respective `UserProfile`.

As in any relational database project, you should seriously consider using [ACID TRANSACTIONS](http://amturing.acm.org/info/gray_3649936.cfm#add_1) in order to guard your data *integrity* and *consistency*.

**2.1.3 Option D**

Let us suppose that, in your domain of discourse of interest, a *Person* can perform two roles: *Administrator* and *Author*. This is where Option D comes into play, and the next assertions are useful in delineating our informational diagram:

- A *Person* may be zero-or-one *Administrator*
- A *Person* may be zero-or-one *Author*
- A *Person* may login via zero-or-one *UserProfile*

In this way, a `Person` holds his or her particular “active” *Usernames* in his or her specific `UserProfile` and, also, can possess a *Handle* in case said `Person` is an `Administrator` and another different *Handle* when carrying out the role of `Author`.

## 3. Possibility with the common ASP.NET Users and Roles approach

You mentioned via comments that you are using ASP.NET MVC as your application development platform and, although I am not sure if you are as well utilizing the common (or default) ASP.NET course of action for handling *Users* and *Roles*, this section can serve as a good reference assuming you have to deal with the typical conditions.

#### 3.1 ASP.NET Users and Roles approach diagram

The approaches suggested in [Figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM6cX.jpg) appear feasible since you would not need to modify the tables that are usually created in ASP.NET apps. As you can see, you would only have to create an additional table for retaining the *Handles* (or *Nicknames*, or *Aliases*, if you prefer) that a given *User* may (or may not) have in regard to a certain *Role* assigned to such *User* in your application program. In other words, the same *User* could hold multiple *Handles*, and the context for each *Handle* instance would be an exact *Role* performed by the *User* at issue.

Attaching a `Handle` column directly to the `UsersInRoles` table *could* be possible too, but it *may have unfavorable consequences* in the ASP.NET authentication and authorization processes, aspects that, as you know, are  of the greatest importance for the security of any app, so this method would require especial research and testing.

[image: Possibility with the common ASP.NET Users and Roles Arrangement]

**3.1.1 Option A**

This method depicts a `Handle` table that is connected to the `UsersInRoles` table by virtue of a composite FK that consists of the `UserId` and the `RoleId` columns. Said `Handle` table has an AK set up for, precisely, the `Handle` column, which implies that a specific *handle* value* could only be INSERTed in one single row.

**3.1.2 Option B**

In this option I have portrayed a `Handle` table that also makes a reference to the `UsersInRoles` table by means of a FK composed of the `UserId` and the `RoleId` columns, but it shows a slightly different approach that displays an AK constituted by the `RoleId` and the `Handle` columns, which would open the chance to have the same handle value repeated in multiple rows, but *only* in combination with disctinct `RoleId` values.

---

## Notes

<sub><sup>**1**</sup> *Integration Definition for Information Modeling* ([IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)) is a highly recommendable data modeling technique that was established as a *standard* in December 1993 by the United States *National Institute of Standards and Technology* (NIST). It is solidly based on (a) some of the theoretical works authored by the *sole originator* of the [relational model](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685), i.e., [Dr. E. F. Codd](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm); on (b) the [Entity-Relationship view](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320440), developed by [Dr. P. P. Chen](http://awards.acm.org/award_winners/chen_6196475.cfm); and also on (c) the Logical Database Design Technique, created by Robert G. Brown.</sub>

<sub><sup>**2**</sup> IDEF1X defines *key migration* as “The modeling process of placing the primary key of a parent or generic entity in its child or category entity as a foreign key”.</sub>

<sub><sup>**3**</sup> An ALTERNATE KEY is a property (or a combination of properties) that holds values that uniquely identify an entity type occurrence but was not chosen as the PK of the pertinent entity type; each entity type can have zero, one or more ALTERNATE KEYs. In an IDEF1X diagram, they are indicated as “AK” plus its respective number, e.g., AK1, AK2, etc. They are usually declared in a logical-level SQL DDL design via (i) a single- or multi-column UNIQUE constraint along with (ii) one or more NOT NULL constraints.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed reply! The team aspect though, I think wouldn't feature in my database. When I used a team as an example, it wasn't in a database sense, but in a social, self organising sense. I'm not sure if this will ring any bells, but the MSN gaming zone (back in the day) allowed multiple usernames. There wasn't a concept of a team, but people had one username for a team they were in, and another personal one. Some sysops had multiple usernames too, one for social gaming and one with admin privileges for moderation (the roles will need to hang off the username table I guess).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `active_username_id` field in your `user` table, as a 1-to-1 relationship. So, from your first example, you would simply remove the `active` field from your `username` table, and add an `active_username_id` to your `user` table. This would remove the ability to have no/multiple active usernames, and probably simplify queries too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is the notion of a `team`. This implies context with respect to your concept of a nickname.

If this is truly the case, I would say that the nickname belongs on the table **join table** between `user` and `team`. In absence of this "context" you're not able to create an association between the user and their multiple nicknames. Sure you could easily have a table of multiple nicknames associated to a user. But without context, which one do you pull?

You didn't mention an RDMS flavor, but [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/44b0b) is a SQL Fiddle demonstrating my answer.