# Designing MySQL Database For Two Different User Types (Staff and Client)?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, rdbms, subtypes

I'm creating a web-app that will connect to a MySQL database.  This app will have 2 users:  a Staff and Client that can both log in from the same login page.

Both Staff and Client share the following common attributes:

- staffID/clientID
- status
- timestamp update
- username
- password
- email
- image profile
- first/middle/last name
- gender
- date of birth
- address
- phone

But the Staff has the unique attributes:

- position
- license
- badge
- date hired

And the Client has the unique attribute:

- company name

**1.)** Would it be advisable to put all the common attributes in one single `Users` table with a column `user_type` to determine whether it's a Staff or a Client that logs in or make two separate tables for `Staff` and `Client` that have the exact same attributes?

**2.)** Would it be advisable to further separate the following attributes:

- gender
- date of birth
- address
- phone

into another table since they will not be queried as much (these attributes are only queried when viewing users' profiles)?  Will this help speed up query time for, say, log ins?

**3.)** Would it be ideal to separate the `image profile` attribute into one table `Image_Files` or keep it within the same table with all the other attributes?

As of now, I'm leaning on making the following tables with columns:

`USERS` table:

- userID [PK] (formerly staffID/clientID)
- status
- timestamp update
- username
- password
- email

`USER_DETAIL` table:

- user_detailID [PK]
- userID [FK]
- gender
- date of birth
- address
- phone

`STAFF_DETAIL` table:

- staff_detailID [PK]
- userID [FK]
- position
- license
- badge
- date hired

`CLIENT_DETAIL` table:

- client_detailID [PK]
- userID [FK]
- company name

`IMAGE_FILES` table:

- imageID [PK]
- userID [FK]
- image pathfile pointer

Is this database design unnecessarily complicated?  If so, how may I streamline it to make it more simpler, faster to query, and yet still satisfy the unique attributes of each entities?

Comment: Do define the faster to query criteria you need to look at what queries you are going to be doing on the dataset. How often is `USERS` considered the criteria in a query vs `STAFF` or `CLIENT`?

Comment: It seems like you can toss the `detailIDs` and promote the `userIDs` to be `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: @RickJames That would accomplish the same thing as making everything into one table.  And if I have 1,000 rows, queries might be affected due to the number of columns in the table.  Also, some attributes are unique to Staff and Client.  Hence, why I can't put them all into one big table.

Comment: @danblack User data needs to be queried every login, browsing their profile pages, and making status reports (for Staff only).

Comment: @JaeBin - 1000 rows is 'tiny', even with dozens of columns, many being `NULL`.  The choice here is not clearcut -- One table vs several tables will make virtually no performance difference and not much difference in handling the data.

Comment: @RickJames What about future scalability if the database fills up with more than 1000 rows?  Even up to 1 million rows?  Also, what about the attributes unique to Staff only?

Comment: @RickJames Moreover, I've been reading advice on not storing image filepaths within the same table, and to keep them separate as possible with an FK constraint.

Comment: @JaeBin - Even at a million rows, the choice is not critical.  By the time you get to a million, you will make several schema changes.  Revisit this question later.

Comment: @JaeBin - In some cases, the deciding issue for _images_ is that adding `<img src=path/to/img>` in HTML is much easier than turning a database column into the equivalent.

Comment: A future reader may find of help [this Q & A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/183129/63644).

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are focusing to much on performance. From the description it seems like the user table will be rather small (say, less than a million users).

Instead you should focus on the functionality you want from the system. There are questions you should ask and design for such as:

- Can a user be both client and staff?
- Can a user be user for several companies?
- Can a user have several adresses, say a business adress and a home adress?
- Do you need to have "time based changes", say that a client should be made active (or inactive) at a future date?
- Do you need to store change information (who and when information was changed)?
- Will you need to support several different login schemas (say through facebook or using some kind of one-time-password)?

My take on this is that I would have one table describing a login user and a second table describing a users role. When a user has successfylly logen in I would check if the users has several roles, and the user would be required to select role: staff or user for one company. This would allow the login to be for one physical person, over time it could evolve to include OTP or challenge response or what is deemed necessary. The user would at any time have zero, one or more selectable roles.

Edit (added): If the user has only one role, there is no need to show any selection. Even if a user has no role right now the system might allow changing adress, mail adress and so on. Role based might allow a user to be administrator for the users at one company. End edit.

In the role table I would have start and stop dates. If necessary from a performance view it would be possible to later add an "active" field but that would be an optimization which I would not add until necessary.