# Login system: how is it possible to model multiple user types identified by only one account?

Tags: database-design

I am trying to model a database consisting of different entities that need to be authenticated through a login system. Let's assume to have two separate entities (Seller and Manager) just like this image:
[image: conceptual model]

as you can see both of them have (only) one account identified by the primary key *username*. I would like to be able to identify one role by its username, so that my system recognises what to do. If we translate this conceptual model in the physical one the resulting model is the following:
[image: physical model]

Is this actually correct?

---

**Update:**
I translated in english all my entities and decided to upload my physical model here in order to explain why i made this *user-centric*:

[image: physical model]

My users are:

- SystemAdministrator
- Owner
- Seller

basically these three roles have logical connection with other entities, how can i keep these logical connections and still have a valid account table (for username, password... info)?

*Thanks in advance and best regards.*

Comment: A future visitor my find of help the (conceptual and logical) design principles described in [answer no. 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/183129/63644) and [answer no. 2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/120530/63644).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should make tables to represent Roles (User, Manager, Seller, etc) I think you could implement something more scalable like this:

[image]

Completely forget about the "*user-centric*" model and think to a lower level, Individuals. *Individuals* can have any number of Accounts and Accounts can have any number of Roles. Individuals can be represented on any number of abstractions around the database or even across databases.

What do you think?

Comment: Your representation makes sense and it's way more abstract than mine. 
By the way, i have updated my question with the project scope and tried to explain why i made it *user-centric* as you mentioned - it's because i wanted to keep a logical view between my business entities. Would you mind having a look on the updated question? Thanks for your help!