# SQL - Many-to-Many relationship with same table and with relationship constraint

Tags: database-design, table, many-to-many

I have a SellerProduct table. Each row within the table represents product information as offered by a seller. The SellerProduct table has the following columns:

```
id (serial, pk)
productName (nvarchar(50))
productDescription (ntext)
productPrice (decimal(10,2))
sellerId (int, fk to Seller table)
```

A product may be the same across sellers, but the productName, productDescription and productPrice can vary per seller.

For example, consider the product TI-89. Seller A may have the the following information for the product:

```
productName = TI-89 Graphing Calc
productDescription = A graphing calculator that...
productPrice 65.12
```

Seller B may have the the following information for the product:

```
productName = Texas Instrument's 89 Calculator
productDescription = Feature graphing capabilities...
productPrice 66.50
```

Admin users will be required to identify that products are the same across various sellers.

I need a way to capture this information (i.e. products are the same across sellers). I could create another table called SellerProductMapper as follows:

```
sellerProductId1 (int, pk, fk to SellerProdcut table)
sellerProductId2 (int, pk, fk to SellerProdcut table)
```

The problem with this approach is that it permits sellerProductId1 and sellerProductId2 to be from the same seller for a given row. That should not be allowed.

How can I capture this many-to-many relationship while enforcing this constraint?

Comment: I apologize for the delay. This fell off my radar when other project demands occurred. Not a good excuse though given your efforts and others to help...Sorry. FYI - I made a few comments and marked your answer as the solution.

Comment: No worries. Best regards.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding sellerProductId1 (int, pk, fk to SellerProdcut table). What are the columns for SellerProductmapper?

Comment: In the OP, the `SellerProductMapper` has two columns, `sellerProductId1` and `sellerProductId2`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your scenario description correctly, you want to manage **two different facts**, so you should have **(a)** one table to store product data that is **independent** of sellers and **(b)** another table to retain product information that comes into play in the context of each **relationship** between products and their corresponding sellers.

## 1. Logical model

I have depicted such approach in the logical **IDEF1X<sup>[1]</sup>** data model shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfsan.jpg) and you can [download it from Dropbox as a PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4d5q07q3jf9uhj/Products%20and%20Sellers%20Data%20Models.pdf).

[image: Figure 1 - Products and Sellers Data Model -Option A]

#### 1.1 Product

As you can see in the referred model, you may use the `Product` entity type (or **table** at the implementation level) to store the *default* (or *base*) values of the product attributes. It can be useful to think about this entity as some kind of *catalogue*. Here is where you can keep the product data that does not depend on sellers.

I have denoted the `Product` PK as `ProductNumber` for expository porposes but, possibly, the use of some sort of `ProductCode` or another similar term might be more suitable or advantageous in your business domain.

#### 1.2 ProductSeller

Then, I have set up a PRIMARY KEY (PK) in the `ProductSeller` **associative entity** which is composed of `SellerId` and `ProductNumber`, and these attributes are, in turn, FOREIGN KEY references to `Party.PartyId` and `Product.ProductNumber`, respectively. This is the place where you could store product names, descriptions and prices as defined by every specific seller.

#### 1.3 Party

I decided to include the `Party` entity in case you have to store sellers that are **either** an `Organization` **or** a `Person`. These three entities are encompassed in a **exclusive Supertype-Subtype** relationship, so [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102069/63644) could be pertinent.

#### 1.4 Implementation considerations

It is important to note that I indicated some attributes as ALTERNATE KEYS (AK plus its fitting number), since this implies that, when they become table columns, they should be set with a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT or UNIQUE INDEX.

As in any relational database development, you should seriously consider using [ACID Transactions](http://amturing.acm.org/info/gray_3649936.cfm#add_1) in order to guard your data integrity and consistency.

## 2. Simplified logical model

If in your case it is only possible for an `Organization` to become a `Seller`, then you can employ a structure like the one I propose in the logical model presented in [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaDQM.jpg), and it is also [downloadable from Dropbox as a PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4d5q07q3jf9uhj/Products%20and%20Sellers%20Data%20Models.pdf).

[image: Figure 2 - Products and Sellers Simplified Data Model - Option B]

With this model, you just have to **migrate<sup>[2]</sup>** the `OrganizationId` PK from `Organization` to `SellerProduct`, and then assign it a **role name<sup>[3]</sup>** like `SellerId` in order to make it more meaningful or, maybe, leave it as `OrganizationId` if you feel more comfortable. After that, you migrate the `Product.ProductNumber` to complete the composition of the `SellerProduct` PK.

## 3. Data entry process

Having discussed the most relevant parts of the two suggested structures, I esteem opportune addressing the process that should take place when the data entry is being carried out. In this respect —with the aid of an application program that communicates with your database— your properly **authorized users** can:

- Inspect carefully the product information detailed by one certain seller.
- Compare it with the rows already contained in the `Product` table.
- If they define that such product instance has not been entered yet and therefore it is not provided by any seller, then they **(1.1)** INSERT a new `Product` row with the *default* or *base* values and also **(1.2)** a new row in the `ProductSeller` table including the suitable `SellerId` (drawn from `Party.PartyId` or `Organization.OrganizationId`) and the `ProductNumber` just created along with the remaining column values holding the product data as described by that seller in particular.
- If, on the contrary, they determine that the product under inspection is already stored in the *catalogue* and, perhaps, provided by one or more distinct sellers too, then they simply **(1)** INSERT a new row in the `ProductSeller` table including the corresponding `SellerId` and `ProductNumber` (taken from `Product.ProductNumber`) values toghether with the complementary column values that contain the product information as designated by the seller at hand.

So, as explained above, the `ProductSeller.ProductNumber` and `ProductSeller.SellerId` would be very useful to cover the following specification:

> Admin users will be required to identify that products are the same across various sellers.

Since having a given `ProductNumber` value referenced from multiple `ProductSeller` rows will assist your database users in the identification and retrieval of those products that are offered by different sellers, who will be recognized by their distinctive `SellerId` value which, of course, points to a precise `Party.PartyId` (or `Organization.OrganizationId`).

## 4. Tracking Product data modifications

#### 4.1 Product History and ProductSeller History

Since it seems reasonable to assume that product data can suffer modifications over time (and, probably, most of the time these modifications will be related to product prices), I deem necessary the inclusion of a mechanism to track these changes. This is the reason for which I incorporated the entity types denominated `ProductHistory` and `ProductSellerHistory` in the above presented logical model.

In this respect, you may find [this post about temporal databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107575/63644) and [this post about data versioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112314/63644) of relevance.

#### 4.2 Handling ProductPrice as a time series

You might be face the need to follow the trail of time-related product modifications **exclusively** when they concern to prices, so you could alternatively make use of the model depicted in [Figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UC4O.jpg), which you can [download from Dropbox as a PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4d5q07q3jf9uhj/Products%20and%20Sellers%20Data%20Models.pdf), as well.

[image: Figure 3 - Products and Sellers Data Model - Option B]

In this way, let us take the `Product` and `ProductPrice` entity types as references. As demonstrated in this alternative model, I have moved the `DefaultPrice` attribute to a new entity, and this new entity has a PK made up of `ProductNumber` (also playing the role of a FK that makes a reference to `Product`) and `CreatedDateTime` (that would mark the exact point in time in which a determined *default* price was inserted).

Consequently, every time that a *default* price value needs to be put up-to-date, your database users only have to INSERT a new `ProductPrice` row, containing the suitable `ProductNumber` taken from `Product` and the new price value. You may use a server function so that you can retrieve and store the exact insertion instant, i.e. `CreatedDateTime`, in a reliable manner.

The *current* or *effective* version of a product *default* or *base* price occurrence would be the row holding the `MAX(ProductPrice.CreatedDateTime)` for a definite `ProductNumber`,  and all the other rows (when they exist) matching the same `ProductNumber` would be the *previous* `DefaultPrice` versions.

You can then employ a comparable approach to handle the changes related to the `ProductSeller` price datum.

---

## Notes

<sub>1. Integration Definition for Information Modeling (**[IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x.htm)**) is a **highly recommendable data modeling technique** that was defined as a **standard** in december 1993 by the United States National Institute of Standards and Technology (**NIST**). It is solidly based on (a) some of the theoretical papers authored by the **originator** of the **Relational Model**, i.e., [**Dr. E. F. Codd**](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm); on (b) the [**Entity-Relationship theory**](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320440), developed by [**Dr. P. P. Chen**](http://awards.acm.org/award_winners/chen_6196475.cfm); and also on (c) the **Logical Database Design Technique**, created by **Robert G. Brown**. It is worth noting that this techinque was **formalized** by way of **first-order logic**.</sub>

<sub>2. IDEF1X defines **key migration** as “The modeling process of placing the primary key of a parent or generic entity in its child or category entity as a foreign key”.</sub>

<sub>3. The use of **role names** is recommended since 1970 by **Dr. Codd** in his seminal paper entitled **[“A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Data Banks”](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685)**. For its part, IDEF1X —keeping fidelity regards **relational** practices— also advocates role naming.</sub>

Comment: Awesome! Very detailed and helpful response! We only have organizations so figure 2 works. We also have a temporal aspect in regards to pricing as you surmised. So, figure 4.2 is very relevant and useful for that.

Comment: @James I'm glade to make a contribution. Your scenario is very interesting (and I consider that some points can be re-used in some other situations), so it required a proper response. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

My first reaction is that your primary key is not sufficient to guarantee uniqueness.  I think you should consider a composite key of ProductId, SellerId.  Even then you could still have duplicates in the table.
I think you really need to backup and look at the real business requirements.  For example just how "faithfully" do you need to capture unique products.  Many manufacturers produce essentially the same product under a profusion of SKU's (look at Toshiba's Laptops sometime) and sometimes provide different SKU's to different distributors/retailers.

Also, as an aside you probably don't want NText for your Production Description.  Surely a few hundred or few thousand characters would be sufficient.

Comment: SellerProduct.id is defined as serial (i.e. auto incrementing). It is a surrogate key and is guaranteed to be unique. It does not refer to the product id. It refers to the SellerProduct id. It is very important to the business to capture products offered by sellers and match which products are the same among different sellers. Although I used a TI calculator as an example, there is no SKU (or other unique way to id) for these type of products. Admins have to do this. +1 - Thanks for the NText suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is why many industries enforce SKU, UPC or any other unique identifier. If you don't have one, you could create one and let them enter this information in the database. Once the information is there then it will be easy to run the queries you need.