# Normalizing a table with a field that generally uniquely identifies a row, but is sometimes null

Tags: postgresql, database-design, normalization

forgive me if this has been asked and answered before.

I'm roughing out a schema for an inventory management system, to be implemented in PostgreSQL. All of our products and services have a sku. *Most* of our products come from the manufacturer or distributor with a separate "item number" (whether it be a distributor's catalog number, manufacturer's model number, whatever). However, not all of them have such a number. We have small assemblies that we make in-house that, generally, don't have item numbers. Our services don't have item numbers. For these reasons, the following CREATE TABLE makes sense to me.

Scenario A:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
   sku            text PRIMARY KEY,
   name           text UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- alternate key
   price          numeric NOT NULL CHECK (price > 0),
   quantity       numeric NOT NULL CHECK (quantity > 0),
   item_number   text -- hmmm...
);
```

However, I have two problems with this.

1. Sometimes (maybe 3% to 5% of the time), the item_number is actually *equal* to the SKU. That is, one of my suppliers in particular affixes to their products what I suspect is not a globally unique SKU, fashioned after their item number.
2. Whether equal to the SKU or not, the item_number (when existent) is in virtually every case sufficient to uniquely identify a product in the domain of my small store.

I'm worried about normalizing this to 3NF. If item_number is sometimes null, it obviously cannot be declared an alternate key. But, semantically, it is a unique identifier, where it exists, in every case I can think of. So does my above table, where every attribute is functionally dependent upon the non-prime attribute item_number *whenever item_number exists*, normalized? I'm thinking no, but I'm certainly not an expert. I thought of doing the following:

Scenario B

```
CREATE TABLE product (
   sku            text PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES product_item_number (sku),
   name           text UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- alternate key
   price          numeric NOT NULL CHECK (price > 0),
   quantity       numeric NOT NULL CHECK (quantity > 0),
);

CREATE TABLE product_item_number (
   sku            text PRIMARY KEY,
   item_number    text
);
```

Since it's really not a requirement that I preserve the functional dependency item_number -> price, item_number -> quantity, etc., scenario B kinda sorta seems reasonable to me. I won't have a non-prime attribute determining any other non-prime attributes.

My final idea was to simply use the sku as the item number in all cases where the item_number is otherwise non-existent, but I wonder whether that's a good practice.

Scenario C

```
CREATE TABLE product (
   sku            text PRIMARY KEY,
   name           text UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- alternate key
   price          numeric NOT NULL CHECK (price > 0),
   quantity       numeric NOT NULL CHECK (quantity > 0),
   item_number    text UNIQUE NOT NULL -- alternate key???
);
```

My concern with scenario C is that there may be cases where a supplier recycles a catalog number with a different sku (maybe?), or situations where two manufacturer's both make a "d57-red" or something like that. In that case, I think I'd have to programmatically prefix offending item_numbers with manufacturer names or something like that.

Of course, maybe I'm over thinking all this.

Thanks for reading.
A couple clarifications, as per MDCCL's comments:

- A sku will always be unique in my domain (The small amount of non-globablly unique supplier-provided SKUs are unlikely to ever collide).
- The item_number will be a public-facing attribute, used both by customers and sometimes myself to identify products. For example, say a customer skips my website and calls me to ask if I have xyz-white; the item_number helps remove ambiguity. The item numbers are unique in my experience (that is, there are no counter examples in my inventory), but that's not a rule, per se. I could have an item_number name space collision one day. Perhaps, if that happened, I would prefix the first three letters of the manufacturer's name to the item_number.
- item_numbers don't always exist. I suppose I *could* provide some sort of "surrogate item_number" for those without one, but an arbitrary item_number would be counter-productive. As explained immediately above, where an item_number exists, it should exist to help myself and my customers disambiguate between products. They might believe they're looking at the wrong product if the item_number is something I concocted myself. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Provided that *Sku* and *ItemNumber* will always imply unique values

I consider that you found the answer already by discovering that, conceptually speaking, *ItemNumber* is an *optional* property; i.e., when you determined that it does *not* apply to each and every one of the occurrences —represented by logical-level rows— of the *Product* entity type. Therefore, the `item_number` column should not be declared as an ALTERNATE KEY (AK for brevity) in the `product` table, as you rightly pointed out.

In this respect, your Scenario B is quite reasonable, as the following conceptual-level formulation demonstrates:

- A *product* may or may not have an *item number*.

In other words, there is a *one to zero or one* (1:0/1) cardinality ratio between *Product* and *ItemNumber*.

Then, yes, you should introduce a new table to deal with the optional column, and I agree that `product_item_number` is a very descriptive name for it. This table should have `sku` constrained as its PRIMARY KEY (PK), so as to ensure that no more than one row with the same `sku` value is inserted into it, just like you did.

It is also important to mention that `product_item_number.sku` should as well be a constrained as a FOREIGN KEY (FK) making a reference to `product.sku`.

Here is a sample SQL-DDL logical-level design that illustrates the previous suggestions:

```
-- You should determine which are the most fitting 
-- data types and sizes for all your table columns 
-- depending on your business context characteristics.

-- Also, you should make accurate tests to define
-- the most convenient INDEXing strategies.

CREATE TABLE product ( 
    sku      TEXT    NOT NULL, 
    name     TEXT    NOT NULL, 
    price    NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
    quantity NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT product_PK        PRIMARY KEY (sku), 
    CONSTRAINT product_AK        UNIQUE      (name), -- AK.
    CONSTRAINT valid_price_CK    CHECK       (price > 0),
    CONSTRAINT valid_quantity_CK CHECK       (quantity > 0)
); 

CREATE TABLE product_item_number ( 
    sku         TEXT NOT NULL, -- To be constrained as PK and FK to ensure the 1:0/1 correspondence ratio between the relevant rows.
    item_number TEXT NOT NULL, 
    --
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_PK            PRIMARY KEY (sku),
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_AK            UNIQUE      (item_number), -- In this context, ‘item_number’ is an AK. 
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_TO_product_FK FOREIGN KEY (sku) 
        REFERENCES product (sku)  
);
```

*Tested on PostgreSQL 11 in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c7b501b32b492e32fe37e0aa7b7bf8b6)*.

Moreover, there is another conceptual formulation that guides in shaping the database design presented above:

- If it exists, the *ItemNumber* of a *Product* must be unique.

So, where the `item_number` column should actually be declared as an AK is right there, in the `product_item_number` table, because said column requires uniqueness protection *only* when the pertinent value is provided, hence the UNIQUE and NOT NULL constraints have to be configured accordingly.

**Missing values and the “Closed World Interpretation”**

The logical SQL-DDL arrangement previously described is an example of the *relational* approach to handle missing values, although it is not the most popular —or usual—. This approach is related to the “Closed World Interpretation” —or “Assumption”—. Adopting this position, (a) the information recorded in the database is always deemed *true*, and (b) the information that is not recorded in it is, at all times, deemed *false*. In this way, one is exclusively retaining facts that are *known*.

In the present business scenario, when a user supplies all the data points that are comprised in the `product` table you have to INSERT the corresponding row and if, and only if, the user made the `item_number` datum available you also have to INSERT the `product_item_number` counterpart. In case that the `item_number` value is unknown or it simply does not apply, you do not INSERT a `product_item_number` row, and that is it.

With this method you avoid holding NULL marks/markers in your *base* tables —and the logical-level consequences that I will detail in the next section—, but you should be aware that this is a “controversial” topic in the database administration ambit. On this point, you might find of value the answers for the Stack Overflow question entitled:

- “[How can I avoid NULLs in my database, while also representing missing data?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4336687)”

**The popular course of action**

I guess, however, that the popular —or common— proceeding would be to have a single `product` table that includes the `item_number` column which, in turn, would be set as NULLable and, at the same time, defined with a UNIQUE constraint. The way I see it, this approach would make your database and the applicable data manipulation operations *less elegant* (as shown, e.g., [in this outstanding Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724420/4807879)), but it is a possibility.

See the successive DDL statements that exemplify this course of action:

```
CREATE TABLE product ( 
    sku         TEXT    NOT NULL, 
    name        TEXT    NOT NULL, 
    price       NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
    quantity    NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
    item_number TEXT    NULL, -- Accepting NULL marks. 
    --
    CONSTRAINT product_PK        PRIMARY KEY (sku), 
    CONSTRAINT product_AK1       UNIQUE      (name), -- AK.
    CONSTRAINT product_AK2       UNIQUE      (item_number), -- Being ‘NULLable’, this is not an AK. 
    CONSTRAINT valid_price_CK    CHECK       (price > 0),
    CONSTRAINT valid_quantity_CK CHECK       (quantity > 0)
);
```

*Tested on PostgreSQL 11 in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e07042260e4f11f3fefbf7d2b57f1581)*.

So, having established `item_number` as a column that can contain NULLs, it is not correct to say, logically speaking, that it is an AK. Furthermore, you would be storing *ambiguous* NULL marks —which are *not* values, no matter if the PostgreSQL documentation labels them that way—, thus it can be argued that the table would not be a proper representation of an adapted mathematical [*relation*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174092/63644) and normalization rules cannot be applied to it.

Since a NULL indicates that a column value is (1) *unknown* or (2) *inapplicable*, it *cannot* be rightly stated that said mark belongs to the `item_number` valid domain of values. As you know, this kind of mark tells something about the “status” of a real value, but it is not a value itself and, naturally, it does not behave as such —and, by the way, it is worth to mention that NULLs behave differently across the distinct SQL database management systems, even across distinct versions of the same database management system—.

Then, if (i) the domain of values of a certain column and (ii) the meaning that said column carries is not *entirely* clear as a result of the inclusion of NULLs:

- How could one evaluate and define the relevant functional dependencies?
- How can it be identified and declared as PRIMARY or ALTERNATE KEY (as in the case of the `item_number`)?

Despite both the *theoretical* and *practical* —e.g. regarding data manipulation— implications that concern to the retention of NULL marks in a database, this is the approach to handle missing data that you will find in the vast majority of the databases built on SQL platforms, since it permits attaching columns for optional values to the base tables of significance and, as an effect, eludes the creation of (a) a complementary table and (b) the associated tasks.

#### The decision

I have presented the two alternatives so that you can determine by yourself which one is more suitable to achieve your objectives.

---

## Assuming that the *Sku* and *ItemNumber* values can eventually be duplicated

There are some points of your question that caught my attention in an particular way, so I listed them:

> - Sometimes (maybe 3% to 5% of the time), the item_number is actually equal to the SKU. That is, one of my suppliers in particular affixes to their products what I suspect is not a globally unique SKU, fashioned after their item number.
> - […] there may be cases where a supplier recycles a catalog number with a different sku (maybe?), or situations where two manufacturer's both make a "d57-red" or something like that. In that case, I think I'd have to programmatically prefix offending item_numbers with manufacturer names or something like that.
> - A sku will always be unique in my domain (The small amount of non-globablly unique supplier-provided SKUs are unlikely to ever collide).

Those points can have remarkable repercussions because they seem to suggest that:

- The *ItemNumber* values can eventually become duplicated and, when that happens, you might evaluate combining two different pieces of information that bear different meanings in the same column.
- It is probable that, after all, the *Sku* values might be repeated (even if it is a small amount of repeated *Sku* instances).

In this regard, it is worth to note that two paramount objectives of a data modelling exercise are (1) determining each individual datum of significance and (2) preventing the retention of more than one of them in the same column. These factors, e.g., facilitate the delineation of a stable and versatile database structure and assist in the avoidance of duplicated information —which helps to maintain the data values consistent with the business rules, via the respective constraints—.

**Alternative to handle *Sku* duplicates: Introducing a `manufacturer` table to the scenario**

Consequently, on condition that the same *Sku* value can be shared across different *Manufacturers*, you could make use of a *composite* PK constraint in the `product` table, and it would be made up of (i) the manufacturer PK column and (ii) `sku`. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE manufacturer (
    manufacturer_number INTEGER  NOT NULL, -- This could be something more meaningful, e.g., ‘manufacturer_code’.
    name                TEXT NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT manufacturer_PK PRIMARY KEY (manufacturer_number), 
    CONSTRAINT manufacturer_AK UNIQUE      (name) -- AK.
);

CREATE TABLE product (
    manufacturer_number INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    sku                 TEXT    NOT NULL,
    name                TEXT    NOT NULL, 
    price               NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    quantity            NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT product_PK                 PRIMARY KEY (manufacturer_number, sku), -- Composite PK.
    CONSTRAINT product_AK                 UNIQUE      (name), -- AK.
    CONSTRAINT product_TO_manufacturer_FK FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_number)
        REFERENCES manufacturer (manufacturer_number),
    CONSTRAINT valid_price_CK             CHECK       (price > 0),
    CONSTRAINT valid_quantity_CK          CHECK       (quantity > 0)
);
```

And, if the *ItemNumber* demands uniqueness preservation *when it is applicable*, then the `product_item_number` table can be structured as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE product_item_number (
    manufacturer_number INTEGER NOT NULL,  
    sku                 TEXT    NOT NULL,
    item_number         TEXT    NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_PK            PRIMARY KEY (manufacturer_number, sku), -- Composite PK.
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_AK            UNIQUE      (item_number), -- AK.  
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_TO_product_FK FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_number, sku)
        REFERENCES product (manufacturer_number, sku)  
);
```

*Tested on PostgreSQL 11 in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=794a0f2b091bc1da03489a48d2bd66d7)*.

In case that *ItemNumber* does *not* require preventing duplicates, you simply remove the UNIQUE constraint declared for such a column, as shown in the next DDL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE product_item_number (
    manufacturer_number INTEGER NOT NULL,  
    sku                 TEXT    NOT NULL,
    item_number         TEXT    NOT NULL, -- In this case, ‘item_number’ does not require a UNIQUE constraint.
    --
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_PK            PRIMARY KEY (manufacturer_number, sku), -- Composite PK.
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_TO_product_FK FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_number, sku)
        REFERENCES product (manufacturer_number, sku)  
);
```

On the other hand, supposing that *ItemNumber* does actually entail avoiding repeated values *exclusively* with regards to the associated *Manufacturer*, you can set up a composite UNIQUE constraint which would consist of `manufacturer_number` and `item_number`, as demonstrated in the code lines below:

```
CREATE TABLE product_item_number (
    manufacturer_number INTEGER NOT NULL,  
    sku                 TEXT    NOT NULL,
    item_number         TEXT    NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_PK            PRIMARY KEY (manufacturer_number, sku),         -- Composite PK.
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_AK            UNIQUE      (manufacturer_number, item_number), -- Composite AK.
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_TO_product_FK FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_number, sku)          -- Composite FK.
        REFERENCES product (manufacturer_number, sku)  
);
```

**When *Sku* values are always unique but a specific *ItemNumber* value can be shared among distinct *Manufacturers***

If you can guarantee that *Product.Sku* will never imply duplicates *but* an *ItemNumber* might be used by distinct *Manufacturers*, you can configure your database as exposed here:

```
CREATE TABLE manufacturer (
    manufacturer_number INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name                TEXT    NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT manufacturer_PK PRIMARY KEY (manufacturer_number), 
    CONSTRAINT manufacturer_AK UNIQUE      (name) -- AK.
);

CREATE TABLE product ( 
    sku      TEXT    NOT NULL, 
    name     TEXT    NOT NULL, 
    price    NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
    quantity NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT product_PK        PRIMARY KEY (sku), 
    CONSTRAINT product_AK        UNIQUE      (name), -- AK. 
    CONSTRAINT valid_price_CK    CHECK       (price > 0),
    CONSTRAINT valid_quantity_CK CHECK       (quantity > 0)
); 

CREATE TABLE product_item_number ( 
    sku                 TEXT    NOT NULL,
    manufacturer_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    item_number         TEXT    NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_PK                 PRIMARY KEY (sku, manufacturer_number),  
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_AK                 UNIQUE      (manufacturer_number, item_number), -- In this context, ‘manufacturer_number’ and ‘item_number’ compose an AK. 
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_TO_product_FK      FOREIGN KEY (sku)
        REFERENCES product (sku),  
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_TO_manufacturer_FK FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_number) 
        REFERENCES manufacturer (manufacturer_number)  
);
```

*Tested on PostgreSQL 11 [in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c50ac847af6fc0d57f8758eb3a575d7d).*

---

## Physical-level considerations

We have not discussed the exact type and size of the `product.sku` column but, if it is “big” in terms of bytes, then it may end up undermining the data retrieval speed of your system —due to aspects of the physical level of abstraction, associated with, e.g., the sizes of the indexes and disk space usage—.

In this manner, you might like to assess the incorporation of an INTEGER column which can offer a faster response than a possibly “heavy” TEXT one —but it all depends on the precise features of the compared columns—. It may well be a `product_number` that, as expected, would represent a numeric value in a sequence standing for the set of recorded `products`.

An expository arrangement that incorporates this new element is the one that follows:

```
CREATE TABLE product ( 
    product_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    sku            TEXT    NOT NULL, 
    name           TEXT    NOT NULL, 
    price          NUMERIC NOT NULL, 
    quantity       NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT product_PK        PRIMARY KEY (sku), 
    CONSTRAINT product_AK        UNIQUE      (name), -- AK. 
    CONSTRAINT valid_price_CK    CHECK       (price > 0),
    CONSTRAINT valid_quantity_CK CHECK       (quantity > 0)
); 

CREATE TABLE product_item_number 
( 
    product_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    item_number    TEXT    NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_PK            PRIMARY KEY (product_number),  
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_AK            UNIQUE      (item_number), -- AK.
    CONSTRAINT product_item_number_TO_product_FK FOREIGN KEY (product_number)
       REFERENCES product (product_number)   
);
```

I highly recommend carrying out substantial testing sessions with a considerable data load in order to decide which keys are more convenient  —physically speaking—, always taking into account the overall database features (the number of columns of all the tables, the types and sizes of the columns, the constraints and the underlying indexes, etc.).

---

## Similar scenario

You business environment of interest presents a certain resemblance to the scenario dealt with [in these posts](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127779/63644), so you might find of relevance some of the discussed points.

Comment: Hi @MDCCL, your revision is very enlightening, in particular the suggestion that I consider using composite keys. Thank you for the deliberate explanation.

Comment: Hi, @Harley, it is my pleasure. If there are aspects you would like to treat, just let me know. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

If your attribute `item_number` is unique, you can leave it in your original table even in case it can have null values. In fact the PostgreSQL [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/sql-createtable.html) says:

> For the purpose of a unique constraint, null values are not considered equal.

So this could be right solution:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
   sku            text PRIMARY KEY,
   name           text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   price          numeric NOT NULL CHECK (price > 0),
   quantity       numeric NOT NULL CHECK (quantity > 0),
   item_number    text UNIQUE
);
```

which is more efficient than solution B, and more simple to program than solution C.

Note that this solution is normalized, so that you do not have any redundancy, neither you have insertion/deletion anomalies.

**Addition**

For a relation to be formally in Boyce Codd Normal Form (which is stricter than the Third Normal Form), for each dependency the determinant must be a (super)key. But first note that the normalization theory usually do not treat null values. See for instance the book of Elmasri, Navathe, “Fundamental of Database Systems". 6th Edition, 2010:

> There is no fully satisfactory relational design theory as yet that includes NULL values

In this case we have at least the dependency:

```
sku → name, price, quantity, item_number
```

and in fact `sku` is a key for the relation.

Then, supposing that there are no null values, if you want `item_number` be unique, there exist another dependency:

```
item_number → sku, name, price, quantity
```

and so, `item_number` is another key.

In this relation there are no other functional dependencies, a part from those derived from these two, and both these dependencies do not violate the the BCNF (both determinants are keys). So the relation is in Boyce Codd Normal Form.

On the other hand, if you consider that `item_number` can have null values, you could assume that the second dependency does not hold, so that the relation is again in BCNF.

Comment: Thanks, Renzo. I appreciate your insights. I have read that portion of the manual. I've also read Umanath and Scamell's "Data Modeling and Database Design" cover to cover, but no situations like this were addressed. For academic purposes, assume item_number always functionally determines every other attribute of product (when item_number exists). If we permit it to be null, then item_number can't be a candidate key. As such, it's a non-prime attribute and so your relation violates 3rd normal form.

Comment: I'm not necessarily suggesting anomalies _will_ occur. I need some time to think about that. Rather, I'm arguing that the product table in your example is not normalized to 3NF. I could be wrong, of course. Maybe this is all academic. Further insights from you would be most welcome. Cheers.

Comment: @Harley, I have added to the answer a more detailed explanation while the relation is normalized.